# clickable array of 2D shape

Tags: java, arrays, graphics

I have an array of 2D object, I want to make those object clickable, on mouse click it have to return their own index in the array, and then I want to change the color of clicked object. How's suppose I do that, I really need advice :)

Comment: Code you please post some code of what you have tried already?

Answer (score 0):

onMouseClick

- iterate through the array and see if the (X,Y) of the click intersect with the shapes
  oooorrrr...
- if the shape indices say something about it's position then you can calculate it based off the mouse's X,Y instead of checking for collision (e.g. 5x5 grid on a 640x480 res means that each square is 128x96px big, so you can get the indices of the square like

  ```
  indexX = mouse.getX() / square.getWidth();
  indexY = mouse.getY() / square.getHeight();
  printLocationAndChangeColor(squares[indexX][indexY]);
  ```

printLocationAndChangeColor() callback will be the one that prints it's arguments (the x,y coords) and change the argument's color to whatever you want.